# saving email body as tiff php

Tags: php, tiff

I want to save the email body (the content of email) in `tiff` format

I am able to download and save it as txt with:

```
$data = imap_qprint(imap_body($imap, $num));
file_put_contents($folder.$timestamp, $data);
```

but I want to save it in `tiff` and the Format of the content should remain exactly as it is.

Any Ideas how to do it in PHP? Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to save it as an image? And why Tiff? Why not jpeg or something?

Comment: I want to Fax it. And It will be Fax cover Page. So the format is important

Comment: You want to Fax it?! Do they still exist? I think there is software out there that lets you fax from email.

Comment: I know but my client needs a product  and only this cover page part is left. Now I cant argue with client.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org/) installed:

```
$txt = $folder . $timestamp;
$tiff = $txt . '.tiff';
$cmd = sprintf("convert text:%s %s 2> /dev/null", $txt, $tiff);
exec($cmd, $output, $return_var);
$return_var == 0 or die("Conversion failed\n");
```

I think there are a lot of other ways tough.